# add project in exsisting solution to source control

Tags: azure-devops, tfvc

I have a solution containing 4 different projects. The solution is under source control (Azure Devops). But 2 of the projects are not marked with a lock indicating that they are under source control. So how can I make them get a lock and be under source control in that solution?

[image]

In the image above I have added the 1 and fourth project manually in Devops, but changes in those projects are not checked in since they are not under source control.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below steps :

1、  Preconditions: you have a solution including 2 projects and project 1  is marked with a lock indicating that they are under source control but project 2 is not.

[image: solution including 2 projects]

2  open “Team Explorer From View “and click “Source Control Explorer” and move project2 you want to upload to the workspace folder

[image: Source Control Explorer]

3 、open “Solution Explorer” and select Project 2,right click and select “Source Control” and click “Check In”
[image: Check In]

4 add a comment and click “Check In”

[image: Add Comment]

5  Now you have added Project 2 into TFVC repro and Project 2  is marked with a lock indicating that they are under source control

[image: Both projects are under source control]

**Update 11/17/2022**

try below method, I've tested in my visual studio 2022 and it works.

reconfigure your workspace and Select "Map & Get" to map your workspace and get the source.then add your projects to the solution. refer to doc:[configure your workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/share-your-code-in-tfvc-vs?view=azure-devops#configure-your-workspace)

[image: Map & Get]

Comment: Hello, for me this does not work. In my solution explorer the 2 projects that is not under source control is not marked with a plus sign, they dont have any sign at all..

Comment: It will marked with a plus sign automatically When you add project in your solution . If not , make sure  your solution is under source control .

Comment: My solution is under source control its just those 2 projects that I cannot add to source control. I even tried to remove them and add a new project with the same name but no luck

Comment: Can you provide screenshots of your solution  tree directory  and Source Control explorer in Team Explorer?

Comment: ok, I have added an image to my original post.

Comment: Go into Source Control Explorer and navigate to your project you should see that 2 projects aren’t  included. Right click on the folder, click on "Add items to folder..." then click on your project folder that’s missing. Click next and this should add it to source control.

Comment: Sorry that did not work. I could add items to the folder as you suggested but there are no locks indicating the projects are under source control, and if I change one item and try to checkin nothing is detected to have changed.

Comment: @MTplus I've updated my answer and try it.

Comment: How the issue is going? Does the updated answer work for you ?

Comment: Thanks but that did not work for me either. I changed the workspace and then get the latest version but the 2 projects in the solution is still without a lock in the solution explorer.....